# Using binary arithmetic and computing for 'y'

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Using binary arithmetic, a number y is computed by taking the n-bit two’s complement
of x − c. If n is eleven, x = 101000010012 and c = 101012 then y =?

How do we solve these type of questions?
 x = 101000010012
-c =       101012
   = 10011110100
then Inverted all the bits 
01100001011
+         1
=01100001011
so far i got this!!

Comment: how do we find bit2's compliment

Comment: Invert all the bits (change $1$s to $0$s and vice-versa), then add $1$. For example, the $2$'s complement of $001011$ is $110100 + 1 = 110101$.

Comment: i still need more help.
i cant get my final answer right

Comment: Could you at least attempt something and show your steps so that we can help you out with where you get stuck?

Comment: I have edited my answer check pliz

Comment: Almost correct, but in the last step $1 + 1 = 10$ (and don't forget to carry).

Comment: how to i do that now pliz can u show me the whole working on how is that to be done..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is given that $y$ is the $2$'s complement of $x-c$. Here $x = (10100001001)_2$ and $c = (10101)_2$. Then $x - c$ is:

$\begin{align}
10100001001 &-\\
10101 &=\\
\hline
10011110100&\\
\hline
\end{align}$

Inverting the bits, we get $01100001011$, and now adding $1$ to this, $y$ is

$\begin{align}
01100001011 &+\\
1 &=\\
\hline
01100001100&\\
\hline
\end{align}$

$\therefore y = 01100001100$.